# How to get an image to always be in the exact same spot no matter the resolution/scale?

Tags: html, css

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="information">
<a href="https://www.com.edu"><img src="https://com-bb-dev.com.edu/branding/themes/as_2012_orig/images/bbbanner.png" 
style="position: absolute;left: 296px;"></a>
</div>
```

When the monitor resolution is 1920x1200 it appears exactly where I want. However, if you resize the window or change the resolution to some lower values the position of the image changes. What is the proper way to make sure that an image aligns with an element below it? I have tried percentages but that does not seem to be any different from static px values.

e.g.

https://i.gyazo.com/cf47cd0ee4ff20b3a9df48b3cc56d44d.png

If you need to see the rest of the page's construction the url is https://com-bb-dev.com.edu. It is verified via SSL.

Current page construction:

```
<div id="information">
<a href="https://www.com.edu"><img src="https://com-bb-dev.com.edu/branding/themes/as_2012_orig/images/bbbanner.png" style="
    position: absolute;
    /* left: 296px; */
    margin-left: 297px;
"></a>

</div>
<div id="loginPageContainer">

  <div id="loginPane">

    <div id="loginContainer">

      <div class="clearfix loginBody">
        <div id="newStu">Students: Your initial log on is your WebAdvisor Username and your password is your seven digit COM ID number. To keep your account secure, please <a href="https://password.com.edu/_layouts/PG/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.aspx">use this site</a> to change your password at your earliest convenience.</div>
<div id="seeClasses">You will not see your course within your Course List in Blackboard until the official start date (review your class schedule).</div>
```

css:

```
#information {
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#loginPageContainer {
    background: #eaeaea;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 569px;
    zoom: 1;
}

#loginPane {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    height: 541px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 22px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 22px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 22px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#loginContainer .loginBody {
    width: 585px;
}
```

Comment: How exactly would you want it? do you want both panels to be right next to each other, or on opposite sides, etc?

Comment: The below panels I could care less about their alignment when zoomed in/out/window resized, I just want the brand to always align above on the left edge with the "Blackboard Learn" pane below it as seen in the Gyazo screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a minute to see what you meant and I had already written a long rant chastising you until I realized what you were really asking.

1) There's no need for you to be using aboslute positioning. What you really need is a container, or one of your existing elements acting like a container.

2) This is where bootstrap would come in very handy. You could just add `<div class="container">` around both elements and it would be perfect.

3) For you, you have no container elements inside `#information` and just your logo `<a>`. So you could mimic the container from the next section with your `<a>` if you can't alter any HTML but at quick glance you're going to need media queries to get it perfect at every resolution. Easiest thing would be to add a container around both problematic sections.

If you can't update the HTML, edit your question and include that detail and maybe I can look at it another way.

Edit: Since you can change your code and assuming you want your background colors to continue to expand the width of the viewport:

```
<div id="information">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="logo"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="logingPageContainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="pane1"></div>
    <div class="pane2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With that structure you can now do CSS like:

.pane1, .pane2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%; /*Change this width as required or split this for each pane if need different widths */
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

That will get you the basic way there. For responsive, you could use media queries because 80% probably won't look great on all devices and the widths of your panes aren't going to look good on all devices without more CSS adjusting the children of each pane. Right now it looks like everything is in static pixels and that's going to always cause problems in percentage widths. This is just a concept though so adjust where needed but that should get you in the right direction. Comment if you need more help.

Comment: I can edit the HTML, so you're just suggesting, add two divs, one around information and one around loginPageContainer, to act as containers? I mean technically loginPageContainer is already the container for the login pane and the announcements pane. If I wrap information in say an "informationContainer" what elements need to be set on it?

Comment: Yes, the loginPageContainer is the container, but you're applying a grey background color to that container and I assumed you wanted to keep that the width of the viewport. If that isn't a requirement, then you could absolutely style what you have already and make them flush. If you do want to have that background expand the entire viewport, check the code I'm adding to my answer above.

Comment: Shoot, loginPane and loginAnnouncements(which are correlated to pane1,pane2 in your example)are IDs, is that fine? Is it okay to just change the identifer from the . to the # for the CSS of loginPane, loginAnnouncements?

Comment: Okay yes that did work, now I just need to some tweaking. Awesome.

Comment: So I'm a bit stuck, I almost have it how I want, however, one issue I have is when I change to 1600x900 resolution, the widths are a bit too much to fit both the login and announcement pane in the same "row". What I did was I adjusted the width % of the container class, but, when I switch back to 1920x1200, it's not centered. Is there a good way to "solve" this?

Comment: I want to say it has something to do with the "float: left", but, from what I can tell the float:left is what's keeping my logo and login pane aligned...

Comment: Oops, I forgot I removed the float:left. Adding it back doesn't help, though.

Comment: Update, I was able to get everything just perfect. Thank you for referencing media queries, I wasn't aware that there was such an easy way to develop a responsive design. All this time I had been employing javascript "hacks" to modify elements. The media reference was what really shined here. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not being offensive but trying to be helpful. It sounds like you don't have too much experience yet with CSS and HTML so you should really checkout Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/css/ It can help you get up and running with limited knowledge of responsive design and have a much cleaner website. This isn't the only thing available though. Some people prefer Foundation etc but regardless, any kind of CSS/HTML framework would really help you tweak everything quickly.

Comment: Basically Bootstrap is a CSS file that you load on your site and it has a lot of pre-defined CSS for classes that you use on your elements. At this stage in your project, you're not going to be able to just drop in Bootstrap and everything plays nice. It's really meant for when you're starting from scratch because doing this will probably affect your site in negative ways if you're not in the beginning stages. If you have time, it's definitely worth considering and weighing your pros and cons.

Comment: Well, I've used bootstrap very, very lightly before, but, all I'm modifying here is a single page that looks nothing like everything that's behind it. It's basically just a login page. So, as you can imagine, there are default login pages, built from the CSS of the application provider. It is easier to just override some of the CSS identifiers and classes in the login file itself than to go on the backend and make the changes there as changes to the direct CSS files do not propagate in a single refresh typically. If I were building a whole site I would definitely look at bootstrap. TY again!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS:

```
#loginPane {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px; //or however many you want, adjust it to make it at the same position.
}
```

That should work.

**EDIT:**
Use this for positioning logo above panel:

```
<script>
var paneOffset=document.getElementById('loginPane').offset();
var panepx=paneOffset.split(',', 1)[0]
document.getElementById('yourImgId').style.left=panepx + 'px';
```

Also, add a `position: absolute;` to your logo.

Comment: Hmmm...not quite, that skews the pane to the right of #loginPane, "loginAnnouncements".

Comment: Yeah, I realized that you wanted the logo above the pane, not the other way around.

Comment: This almost works but when I begin to adjust the "left" element the loginPane overlaps/goes under the loginAnnouncements pane. Any ideas? I set the position to absolute for the loginAnnouncements pane, that sort of works, but if I resize the window, the panes overlap. If I'm going to resize the window or have a lower resolution I'd prefer that the panes at least "stack" on top of each other, not overlap.

Comment: I don't think you're fully understanding OP's question. He doesn't require any absolute positioning or scripts to achieve what he wants.